# Drupal 7 CMIS Views Error

Tags: drupal-7, alfresco

I successfully connected my alfresco and drupal using cmis api module. The problem is when I try using cmis views module, created a cmis view and display it into a block, the errors appears.

Does anyone understand this error?

```
HTTP call to [http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/s/cmis/queries] returned [500]. Response: Web Script Status 500 - Internal Error Web Script Status 500 - Internal Error The Web Script /alfresco/s/cmis/queries has responded with a status of 500 - Internal Error. 500 Description: An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request 
Message:09040351 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 090414624 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js': 090414623 Request failed 500 /solr/alfresco/cmis?q=select+d.cmis%3Aname%2C+t.cm%3Adescription%2C+t.cm%3Atitle%2C+d.cmis%3AlastModificationDate%2C+d.cmis%3AcontentStreamMimeType%2C+d.cmis%3AobjectId%2C+d.cmis%3AcontentStreamLength+from+cmis%3Adocument+as+d+join+cm%3Atitled+as+t+on+d.cmis%3Aobjectid+%3D+t.cmis%3Aobjectid+where+in_folder%28d%2C+%27workspace%3A%2F%2FSpacesStore%2Fee463364-0808-4277-8881-d5bfb169bddc%27%29+ORDER+BY+d.cmis%3Aname+ASC&amp;wt=json&amp;fl=*%2Cscore&amp;rows=2147483647&amp;df=TEXT&amp;start=0&amp;locale=en_US&amp;fq=%7B%21afts%7DAUTHORITY_FILTER_FROM_JSON&amp;fq=%7B%21afts%7DTENANT_FILTER_FROM_JSON &nbsp; Exception:org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException - 090414623 Request failed 500 /solr/alfresco/cmis?q=select+d.cmis%3Aname%2C+t.cm%3Adescription%2C+t.cm%3Atitle%2C+d.cmis%3AlastModificationDate%2C+d.cmis%3AcontentStreamMimeType%2C+d.cmis%3AobjectId%2C+d.cmis%3AcontentStreamLength+from+cmis%3Adocument+as+d+join+cm%3Atitled+as+t+on+d.cmis%3Aobjectid+%3D+t.cmis%3Aobjectid+where+in_folder%28d%2C+%27workspace%3A%2F%2FSpacesStore%2Fee463364-0808-4277-8881-d5bfb169bddc%27%29+ORDER+BY+d.cmis%3Aname+ASC&amp;wt=json&amp;fl=*%2Cscore&amp;rows=2147483647&amp;df=TEXT&amp;start=0&amp;locale=en_US&amp;fq=%7B%21afts%7DAUTHORITY_FILTER_FROM_JSON&amp;fq=%7B%21afts%7DTENANT_FILTER_FROM_JSON
  org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:333)
  org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryLanguage.executeQuery(SolrQueryLanguage.java:49)
  org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrCMISQueryServiceImpl.query(SolrCMISQueryServiceImpl.java:93)
  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1898.invoke(Unknown Source)
  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
  org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:65) 
  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) 
  org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) 
  $Proxy140.query(Unknown Source) 
  org.alfresco.repo.cmis.rest.CMISScript.query(CMISScript.java:683) 
  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1897.invoke(Unknown Source) 
  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
  org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:155) 
  org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:243)  
  org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:76)  
  org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c4._c0(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js:67)  
  org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c4.call(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js)  
  org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:393)  
  org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2834)  
  org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c4.call(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js)  
  org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c4.exec(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js)  
  org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.executeScriptImpl(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:483) 
  org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:191)  
  org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.execute(ScriptServiceImpl.java:212)  
  org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.executeScript(ScriptServiceImpl.java:174)  
  org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryScriptProcessor.executeScript(RepositoryScriptProcessor.java:102)  
  org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.executeScript(AbstractWebScript.java:1193)  
  org.alfresco.repo.cmis.rest.CMISWebScript.executeScript(CMISWebScript.java:46)  
  org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:86)  
  org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$2.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:393)  
  org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:388)  
  org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:462)  
  org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:500)  
  org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:316)  
  org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:372)  
  org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)  
  org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:118) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  
  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)  
  org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:58)  
  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)  
  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)  
  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)  
  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)  
  org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)  
  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)  
  org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)  
  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)  
  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)  
  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:861)  
  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)  
  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1584)  
  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) 
Exception:org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException - 090414624 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js': 090414623 Request failed 500 /solr/alfresco/cmis?q=select+d.cmis%3Aname%2C+t.cm%3Adescription%2C+t.cm%3Atitle%2C+d.cmis%3AlastModificationDate%2C+d.cmis%3AcontentStreamMimeType%2C+d.cmis%3AobjectId%2C+d.cmis%3AcontentStreamLength+from+cmis%3Adocument+as+d+join+cm%3Atitled+as+t+on+d.cmis%3Aobjectid+%3D+t.cmis%3Aobjectid+where+in_folder%28d%2C+%27workspace%3A%2F%2FSpacesStore%2Fee463364-0808-4277-8881-d5bfb169bddc%27%29+ORDER+BY+d.cmis%3Aname+ASC&amp;wt=json&amp;fl=*%2Cscore&amp;rows=2147483647&amp;df=TEXT&amp;start=0&amp;locale=en_US&amp;fq=%7B%21afts%7DAUTHORITY_FILTER_FROM_JSON&amp;fq=%7B%21afts%7DTENANT_FILTER_FROM_JSON
  org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:195) Exception:org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException - 09040351 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 090414624 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js': 090414623 Request failed 500 /solr/alfresco/cmis?q=select+d.cmis%3Aname%2C+t.cm%3Adescription%2C+t.cm%3Atitle%2C+d.cmis%3AlastModificationDate%2C+d.cmis%3AcontentStreamMimeType%2C+d.cmis%3AobjectId%2C+d.cmis%3AcontentStreamLength+from+cmis%3Adocument+as+d+join+cm%3Atitled+as+t+on+d.cmis%3Aobjectid+%3D+t.cmis%3Aobjectid+where+in_folder%28d%2C+%27workspace%3A%2F%2FSpacesStore%2Fee463364-0808-4277-8881-d5bfb169bddc%27%29+ORDER+BY+d.cmis%3Aname+ASC&amp;wt=json&amp;fl=*%2Cscore&amp;rows=2147483647&amp;df=TEXT&amp;start=0&amp;locale=en_US&amp;fq=%7B%21afts%7DAUTHORITY_FILTER_FROM_JSON&amp;fq=%7B%21afts%7DTENANT_FILTER_FROM_JSON
  org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:970)
Server:Community v4.0.0 (7) schema 5,025 Time:Oct 4, 2012 12:45:56 PM
Diagnostics:Inspect Web Script (org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post)
```

Comment: It looks like the repo is trying to talk to SOLR but failing - are you sure that you've correctly configured SOLR for Alfresco and it's running?

Comment: Did you write the query yourself or is this a query that the CMIS Views module is executing? If you wrote the query yourself, have you confirmed that it functions properly when executed through some other CMIS client, like the CMIS workbench or within the Alfresco Share node browser?

Answer (score 1):

CMIS Views has had an issue with SOLR until last week when I updated - please check the [latest version](http://drupal.org/project/cmis_views/)

Comment: CMIS view is not fetching all child folders and their content in a cmis query is there a way so that I can get all nested data by linking to root folder ??